# Accessing text from a Raphael Js Set

Tags: javascript, web, set, raphael

I created using raphael a set that contains numbers.

```
var mySet = paper.set()

for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
var number = paper.text(10,10, i);  //my number is " i "
mySet.push(number);
}
```

My problem is that I want to access my set and pick the number like so i can compare it later..

```
var numberFromSet = mySet[4].myNumber //this does not work, it's just to explain what I want
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work" ? can you show some error messages or something ? also if you can explain a bit clearer what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I dont have error messages, my job consists on creating a set of numbers, and compare them later like so : if( mySet[0] > mySet[1] ) .... the problem is that i dont know how to get the value of each element of the set !

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added things to a set, you can do:

```
var i = 0;
set.forEach(function(el) {
    if(i == 4) {
        console.log(el); // Here el will be your paper.text(10, 10, 4)
    }
    i++;
});
```

to act on a specific item of the set.

---

Here is a link to the set documentation for reference :

> http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Set

Comment: Thank's for the link !!! Like i explained , i want to get the value of each element of the set , since it's a text, i dont know how to get the value of it in order to compare it later !